# Retrieve and update child data in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with retrieving and updating a value from Firebase realtime database:

```
reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Items").child(a);
        reff.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Items items = dataSnapshot.getValue(Items.class);
                    Integer na = items.getItemQuantity();

                    if (na <= 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(CheckOut.this, "Out of Stock", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        na--;
                        snap.child("itemQuantity").getRef().setValue(na);
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Error log on line 60 from the if-else.

Comment: Post your error

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Also, if the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/PINtCV8) . I can't post image directly. @AlexMamo

Comment: What is the value of `a` in `.child(a)`? And do you want to get a single child or all children under `Items` node?

Comment: a is the node of uid. I want to get the value of itemQuantity. @AlexMamo

Comment: As I see, `a` is the the barcode, or I am misunderstand something? And you want to  get the value of `itemQuantity` of a single child or of all children? Please responde to both questions.

Comment: yes a is the barcode that i will receive from barcode. itemQuantity of a single child. @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your last comment:

> yes a is the barcode that i will receive from barcode. itemQuantity of a single child.

To get the value of `itemQuantity` property of a single child, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference barcodeRef = rootRef.child("Items").child("1234567781");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long itemQuantity = dataSnapshot.child("itemQuantity").getValue(Long.class);
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(itemQuantity));

        //Do what you need to do with itemQuantity
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
barcodeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
14
```

The problem in your code is that you are looping through the `dataSnapshot` object using `getChildren()` method when is actually not necessary. You should only get the correct reference as in the above code and simply use the value of `itemQuantity` property as needed.